# Calculating means and confidence intervals for groups with multiple observations in each subject using the NLME package in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I need your help to identify group means and calculate the corresponding 95% confidence intervals for a set of independent samples with 2 dependent observations within each of those samples. I'm using R with the `NLME` package. Below is a simplified example with a similar structure to my actual data.

Let's assume that both wheels of a total of 7 independent bicycles (n=7) were either equipped with very robust tires (n=4 with `tire=1`) or standard tires (n=3 with `tire=0`), both with a profile of 10.0mm depth. All bikes were used to ride the same cumulative distance, but based on the riding style and road conditions, the tires mounted on one bike might be more similar to each other, than the ones on a different bike. After the distance was reached, the profile depth was measured (possible range 0.0 to 10.0 mm) on all tires (a total of 14 observations). Below is the described dataset:

```
> example
   ID tire depth
1   A    0  3.67
2   A    0  3.67
3   B    0  1.33
4   B    0  3.33
5   C    0  1.33
6   C    0  1.67
7   D    1  6.17
8   D    1  4.00
9   E    1  2.37
10  E    1  5.50
11  F    1  3.50
12  F    1  4.67
13  G    1  5.17
14  G    1  5.83
```

In order to assess whether `tire 1` is better than `tire 0` in terms of wear, I've used the `lme` function of the `NLME` package.

```
> summary(lme(depth ~ tire, data = example, random = ~1 | ID))
```

I've interpreted the following output as a mean difference of 2.15mm in favour of the robust tire (p=0.027).

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: example 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  51.09194 53.03156 -21.54597

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | ID
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:   0.3138429 1.207888

Fixed effects: depth ~ tire 
              Value Std.Error DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept) 2.50000 0.5253550  7 4.758687  0.0021
tire        2.15125 0.6949794  5 3.095415  0.0270
 Correlation: 
     (Intr)
tire -0.756

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-1.8180875 -0.7997771  0.2085848  0.8333573  1.2146423 

Number of Observations: 14
Number of Groups: 7
```

Using the DF and the Std. Error of the output I'm able to calculate the 95% CI of the effect of the robust tire when compared with the standard tire (i.e. 2.15mm, 0.36 to 3.94mm).

However, I would like to describe the means and the corresponding 95% CI of each individual group. That is, we observed a profile depth of 4.65mm (X.XX to X.XX) in the robust tires and 2.5mm (X.XX to X.XX) in the standard tires, in a way that still takes into account that not all observations are independent.